# Mysql repeating incremental numbers?

Tags: mysql

How can I get Mysql to incrementally generate a number between 0 to 99999 and add it to the record? Also once 99999 is reached its starts back at 0.

Answer (score 1):

Generate an ever-incrementing number (e.g., a standard auto_increment) and then when selecting the data (or via a view), run it through mod 100000:

```
⋮
99998  % 100000 = 99998
99999  % 100000 = 99999
100000 % 100000 = 0
100001 % 100000 = 1
⋮
```

You can make this transparent by creating a view for select:

```
CREATE SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW whatever AS
  SELECT
    foo, bar, baz, autoid % 100000 AS autoid, taz
  FROM base_table;
```

Unfortunately, this view will probably not be updatable and MySQL doesn't support `INSTEAD OF` triggers, so you'll have to send writes to the underlying table.

Comment: do you think it would just be better if I let php do this instead?

Comment: @EddyR: No idea if it'd be better to let PHP do this; you haven't described at all *why* you want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You want [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Although getting it to reset at 99999 might be a problem. I would also question your requirement that it work that way.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to reset `auto_increment` unless you delete rows, truncate the table, or recreate the column.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reset it, you can create a trigger:

```
create trigger auto_number before insert on `sometable`
begin
    new.autoid = coalesce((select max(autoid)+1 from sometable),0) % 1000000
end
```

Essentially, when an `insert` occurs, this just sets the `autoid` column as the next largest ID. However, it uses modulo to ensure that the number repeats itself at 1,000,000.

Comment: This won't work. You'll hit the max autoid, and then max(autoid) will become a constant. So you'll repeatedly generate the same ID. Not to mention that there had better be a nice index, or this will be /slow/.

Comment: @derobert: ....that's what the OP asked for. 0 to 99999, then repeat it all over again.